# Why keydown listener doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events, onkeydown

Im trying to run this in IE 8 but it doesn't work, any idea? It works in Firefox, Chrome, Opera...

```
preventBackspace();

function preventBackspace() {
    try {
        if (window.addEventListener) {
            window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, true);
        } else if (window.attachEvent) { // IE 
            alert(window);
            window.attachEvent("onkeydown", onKeyDown);
        } else {
            document.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, true);
        }
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
    }
}

function onKeyDown(e) {
    alert("test!");
}
```

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ubfBq/

window.attachEvent is defined and the event listener added. But it never shows "test!" alert.

I read something about useCapture flag, which is possible to use in the other methods. It captures the key press on the window before the event "goes down". Internet Explorer doesn't seem to allow/use this. Is that the problem? If yes, how can I solve it?

Comment: You can better use jQuery instead of reinventing the wheel. It solves lots of different things with the awful browser called IE

Comment: Yes the thing is that this is a very very small javascript section inside a flex project and I don't want to load JQuery just for few methods.

Comment: Ok, but i think that is a false argument and you create a problem yourself when a solution is already there.

Comment: Why false, if I see it makes sense to use JQuery I will, but I'm not going to add a library just because 1 or 2 functions.

Comment: I know what you are saying and i understand the reason but as i know everything starts 'little' and can grow in the future because it needs more functionality. What will you do, you add a framework. Problem with this is extra code that was not needed when using a framework (you will get different implementations of same things on the long run). That's all i want to say about it. I have seen it too many times. So many companies rewrote there software because it was a mess after several years.

Comment: I'm not trying to bash on jQuery - it is an awesome library that has changed the way javascript is developed. However, the amount of usage of libraries that people seem to think are necessary to accomplish something is way out of place. How many questions do you see with a simple question where someone recommends a jQuery plugin? Drives me nuts!

Comment: I never said that you bash jQuery. jQuery plugin != jQuery, i agree that using plugins is most of time not the way to go to keep it simple, it can be bloated when you rely on plugins and not all plugins are well written (or missing options). In fact, i use jQuery only to reduce browser specific things (especially IE, the evil browser) to keep it 'compatible'. When something changes for some reason, you only have to download a new jQuery version. That is exactly what i want to try to say to you, don't reinvent the wheel when somebody do it for you, it makes your live easier on the long run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use document.attachEvent instead. :]

Answer (score 12):

It appears that only IE9 and later support binding `keydown` on `window`: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html#t00

Instead, bind it to the `document` for IE:

```
function preventBackspace() {
    try {
        if (window.addEventListener) {
            window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, true);
        } else if (document.attachEvent) { // IE 
            alert(document);
            document.attachEvent("onkeydown", onKeyDown);
        } else {
            document.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, true);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is also correct and more extensive but the other person was correct and first :)