# angular 2 HostListener - keydown space event doesn't work in IE

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular2-template

I have a problem with **@HostListener** in IE11.
I need to catch when the user uses keydown event for space, my code very simple and it works fine in Chrome and FireFox but doesn't work in IE.

```
import {Component, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent {
    @HostListener('window:keydown.control.space', ['$event'])
    @HostListener('window:keydown.space', ['$event'])
    spaceEvent(event: any) {
        alert('space key!');
    }
}
```

In the IE developer tools, I don't see any errors or warnings, and I don't know how to resolve this problem.
Any suggestion how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Which version of IE are you using. The older versions of IE don't support various event. This then is more of a restriction for you.

Comment: have a look here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507200/why-keydown-listener-doesnt-work-in-ie

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found solutions. IE doesn't work correctly yet with many various events and need to use `@HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])` and then catch some **keyCode**

Example:

```
import {Component, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent {

    @HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
    spaceEvent(event: any) {
        if(event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 32)
            console.log('ctrl + space');
        else if(event.keyCode == 32)
            console.log('space');
    }
}
```